# Leaflet setView with non lat/long CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, utm

Is it possible to use [setView](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview) when using an alternative CRS?

```
var map = L.map('map',{crs: L.CRS.EPSG26915}).setView([4970081,477018], 13);
// Returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'latLngToPoint' of undefined
```

I assume it's related to using a CRS that isn't lat/long.

To clarify in regards to the first comment...

```
var map = L.map('map'.setView([44.8846225,-93.2203424], 13); // Works fine
var map = L.map('map',{crs: L.CRS.EPSG26915}).setView([44.8846225,-93.2203424], 13); // Same error as above.
```

Comment: What happens if you pass lat/lng? Does it 1) run without errors and 2) display the correct view?

Comment: var map = L.map('map',{crs: L.CRS.EPS26915}).setView([44.8846225,-93.2203424], 13); returns the same error and displays no content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([44.8846225,-93.2203424], 13, L.CRS.EPSG26915);
```